# Send Nagios data to central monitoring server

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I have Nagios set up on three disjoint networks that are all behind firewalls. The monitoring is working great and I'm getting the hang of the somewhat complex configuration. I have a server that is outside of these networks that could be made available to them. What I would like to do, ideally, is have these Nagios servers inside of the firewalls continue to do their normal monitoring and send out their notifications as they have been, but I would like them all to send their data to the server that I have outside of the firewalls.

Essentially, this server would be a place where I could see everything going on inside of each disjoint network at once, and the only things contacting it would be other other Nagios servers. Firewall configs are not an issue, I just have no idea how to configure this in Nagios.

I have Nagios 3.2.1 running on all monitoring servers, compiled from source on CentOS 5.5 monitoring Windows Servers with NSClient++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nagios does has a collector: NSCA. You set that up on the master server and define a ocsp_command on each of the slaves to send its service check results to the master.

This is a well-documented setup. See http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/distributed.html

Comment: This looks promising for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios does not have any specific collector, however you could give it a try to this module [link text](http://dnx.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the already mentioned [DNX](http://dnx.sf.net/) you should take a look at [Merlin](http://www.op5.org/community/projects/merlin). Also make sure you read the section on [Distributed Monitoring](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/distributed.html) in the Nagios manual.

Answer (score -1):

[NDO Utils](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nagios/files/ndoutils-1.x/) includes a MySQL backend for Nagios. You could point the NDO plugin at a central MySQL server and analyzing the data from there. If you're happy with your current distributed monitoring/notification setup, this is probably the simplest solution.

--edited to reflect that NDO Utils is a separate module

Comment: One of the backends which can be used with NagVis is NDOUtils, but it's not part of NagVis but an official Nagios addon.

Comment: True, I couldn't find a direct link to NDO at the time, but I usually install it along with NagVis so that's why I used that link. Here's a more direct one I found today 

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nagios/files/ndoutils-1.x/