# Push monitoring data from Nagios/Zenoss to another system

Tags: nagios, zenoss

I have built a system which does various types of time-series analysis and now I would like to feed it data from a monitoring tool. Since I have Nagios set up already in my test environment, I prefer to get it from there. But as a second choice I could get access to a test Zenoss instance, and would appreciate answers for Zenoss as well.

**What I want**

I want time-series for multiple KPIs on multiple devices.

Ideally I would be able to specify the data format, but as long as it contains the information I need I am happy to transform it upon receipt. The information I need is just

- The device identifier e.g. *10.2.42.2* or *Ubuntu-42A*
- The component being monitored e.g. *CPU* or *Memory*
- The KPI e.g. *%Usage*, *KBytes Available*
- The value of the KPI
- The timestamp

Finally, I would like to send the data via HTTP (for now, later via HTTPS).

I can already do this in the case of an alert - for example when a threshold is breached I know how to configure Nagios to call a simple script of mine with the device IP etc. as parameters - and my script executes the HTTP request. But I haven't seen how this can be set up to fire on *every* poll.

**What I don't want**

I don't want alert data, I want the raw time-series.

I don't want to poll Nagios to get this data - the polling intervals would vary and I would like to avoid unnecessary network traffic.

I checked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/160885/send-nagios-data-to-central-monitoring-server) but that seemed to send data from slave Nagios nodes to a master **Nagios** node.

Comment: The protocol is documented, the source code is freely available and can be modified, the application is tested. Why don't you want to implement a gateway from NCSA to your app?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I was looking for a solution which did not involve touching the Nagios code: (1) fear of getting overwritten by an upgrade, and (2) a customer on whose infra this would eventually get deployed may simply not allow it. For now that is exactly what I intend to do, but I'd still like another long-term solution if one exists.

Comment: You don't need to change either the Nagios code nor the code of the system which is sinking the data - you build a gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the pieces that are intended for distributed monitoring.

For example, use an [ocsp command](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configmain.html#ocsp_command) to send all check results elsewhere. The command def can point to a script that pushes perfdata via curl or similar.

Comment: My Nagios guy says this is likely to work, I will verify next week and accept your answer if it does. Thanks very much

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly. I will detail the steps we took in a separate answer now.

Answer (score 0):

In `nagios.cfg` we added

- `obsess_over_services=1`
- `ocsp_command=OUR_COMMAND_NAME`

Then we defined the new command in `commands.cfg`:

- `command_name     OUR_COMMAND_NAME`
- `command_line     /path/to/our/script`

The script receives the following parameters:

1. Host name
2. Service Description
3. Service State
4. Message from the relevant plugin

Referring to my question: the device I wanted is this host name, and the component & KPI can be extracted from the service description and plugin message.

I do however need to do a little parsing work to get these values, since the plugin message is written more for humans than machines e.g.

```
OK - 1.05 GB used (1.05 GB RAM + 0.00 GB SWAP, this is 32.4% of 3.24 GB RAM)
```

but at least the format is consistent so I'm not complaining.