# Push monitoring data from Zenoss to another system

Tags: zenoss

We have built a system that does time-series analysis on real-time streaming data. We would now like to be able to push events from monitoring solutions into our system. We have figured out how to get Nagios to push the data into our system from [Push monitoring data from Nagios/Zenoss to another system](https://serverfault.com/questions/527844/push-monitoring-data-from-nagios-zenoss-to-another-system) and now would like to do the same with Zenoss version 2.5.2.

1. We have looked at Zenpacks and realize that they are a means to extend the systems monitoring capability (monitor new devices, services etc).
2. We have looked at the source code and understood that serveral daemons use the CollectorDaemon to write data into RRD files. As much as possible we do not want to modify the source code.
   We also don't want to poll the rrd files for changes, because events would be written at varying intervals and that would potentially conflict with our polling.

Basically, we want to a hook into Zenoss system such that we capture and send events (monitoring and event data), to our listener, as soon as possible

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jangaraj/ZenPacks.JanGaraj.DataMirroring

This zenpack mirror data real time - it's Python monkey patch of "writeToRRD" function and you will need some devel skills for implementation. Or ping me and I'll provide my service for you :-).

ZenPack was developed for Zenoss 4.2.5, but it should be modified for Zenoss 2.x easily. You only need to find and patch right "writeToRRD" function in 2.x version.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Jan Garaj. I should have mentioned we are working with Zenoss v2.5.2. Have updated my question. We will however take a look at the ZenPack and post an update.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Jan Garaj. This is exactly what we are doing.